# Adding a 2nd Hard drive causing intermittent restart on server

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, sata

I'm in the middle of configuring a server with circa 6tb storage.
I've got 8x 1TB drives, using a 3ware RAID card (9650SE)

The server also (currently) has 1 additional 250gb SATA drive, with the OS (Windows Server 2008 standard 64 bit) installed on it.

I updated the drivers for the RAID card to the Windows 2008 drivers.

I'm trying to connect an additional hard drive, and configure it as a mirror.
The system appears to work fine, but then if i connect the 2nd hard drive, it intermittently restarts - no BSOD or error, just a straight restart.

Is this a power problem? Or something else I'm missing...

Answer (score 4):

the power suspicion seems most likely - how big is your power supply, and what exactly do you have connected at this point?

Comment: +1, sounds like you are out of juice

Comment: It's got - DC OUTPUT - 500W (MAX) on there...

I've got 
- 8x 1tb drives (in front loading hot-swap caddy), 
- 1x sata drive plugged into mainboard
- raid card
- DVD drive

Is there anything i could do in the short term?

Comment: under-clock the proc and memory, if possible remove drive

Comment: best thing to do is add up the wattage of everything in the box (newegg had a decent estimator here: http://educations.newegg.com/tool/psucalc/index.html , and you really should get it exact) and buy a high quality power supply from thermaltake or antec or the like.  just make sure you find a couple positive reviews on it first.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting enough power to all of the devices. Is this a white-box server or a branded one? 500W is not enough for a powerhouse server, it should be more in the order of 1000W. 9 hard drives and a cd-rom, plus a CPU and MB, no way on 500W.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem connection on SATA?  We fought a problem here for months, replacing the motherboard, disks 3 times, updated BIOS, etc.  It turned out the problem was merely the SATA cable.  The connector connected OK to the backplane, but there was some wiggle.  New cable, no problems.  Sometimes with big problems we look for bigger things, while it is the small thing that is the poison.